# How to trigger Cortana Programmatically?

Tags: windows-phone, cortana

Is there a way to use VoiceCommand methods used to programaticlly trigger Cortana as if the Cortana has registered "Hey Cortana" to begin listening?

Comment: What platform are you targeting? Windows Phone 8.1 or UWP?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same question, but for Windows 10. Found a solution: on Windows 10, you can trigger Cortana with `Win + C` key stroke combination. To get this working programmatically, you would need interop with the Win32 `SendInput` method. Fortunately there is a NuGet package [Windows Input Simulator](http://www.nuget.org/packages/InputSimulator/), that does just this:

```bsh
Install-Package InputSimulator
```

With that installed I was able to trigger Cortana from a WPF app using:

```cs
var sim = new InputSimulator();
sim.Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.LWIN, VirtualKeyCode.VK_C);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible the closest you can get is using something like this:

```
async static void LaunchCortana(bool untrusted, string searchText)
    {
        // The URI to launch
        string uriToLaunch = @"http://www.bing.com/";
        searchText = "search?q=" + searchText.Replace(" ", "+");
        var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch + searchText);

        // Set the option to show a warning
        var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
        options.TreatAsUntrusted = untrusted;

        // Launch the URI with a warning prompt
        var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri, options);

        if (success)
        {
            // URI launched
        }
        else
        {
            // URI launch failed
        }
    }
```

or

```
        await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("bing://home"));
```

It works in **Windows Phone 8.x only** and utilizes the fact that Cortana disables Bing.com , **but you can't use it to launch Cortana commands.** It will just starts a Web search.